# Should I use http or https for tracking links?

Tags: http, https, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, http-referer

I want to build a service that helps people tracking their links. Visitors click on my link url.com/123, they will be redirected to the destination website as below:

Visitors in site A --> url.com/123 (301 redirect) --> site B

Should I use http or https for the link url.com/123 so that I and my customers (the owner of site B) can see the referring site (site A)?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS.  Always and forever.

Protect and offer privacy to your users.  Ideally, your domain should use name servers that provide [DNS over HTTPS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/dns-over-https).